# Bulk update with LINQ based on list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table that stores information of all the contacts that were added for sending SMS campaign.

Every SMS is associated with campaign. campaignid is used in the record for maintaining that.

I receive the sent `mobile_numbers` and `campaign_id` from service provider once the blast is done for campaign.

Now I need to iterate smscontacts table and do the following.

First Get all the records having `campaign_id` . Update the table by updating column `issent` as 1 for all the contacts that have mobile number in `mobile_numbers` list sent by provider after blast.

Edit:

Find rows that have column value for mobile number column in list `mobile_numbers` and update other columns value called for these records.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: sam, i have list having mobile numbers. i need to iterate in table and get all records that have mobile number from list. and then update there issent status as sent by setting it 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `MobileNumber` property is a string and it is null, empty string or white space when it's not set, do the following.

```
// Get contacts that have a mobile number
IQueryable<Contact> contactsWithANumber = context.Contacts.Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.MobileNumber));

// foreach
foreach(Contact c in contactsWithANumber)
{
    c.IsSent = 1;
}

// .ForEach()
contactsWithANumber.ForEach(c => c.IsSent = 1);

// Update in db.
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ExecuteCommand to update multiple records:

```
yourContext.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE YourTable SET issent= 1 WHERE YourCondition");
```

For information see [DataContext.ExecuteCommand Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not linq and is not recommended with EF

Comment: Hi Sam, the ExecuteCommand method is very usefull to do massive updates, because all the work is realized by the SqlServer engine, and its not necessary retrieve all records, updates and next do a submit changes.

Comment: this is now dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand I believe.